# PHP фреймвок, который научит как архитектурно правильно нужно писать веб-приложения

Tags: php, framework

Пересмотрел кучу фреймворков, но все еще задаюсь вопросом какой именно фреймворк нужно знать каждому php-шнику. Я не говорю о том какой лучше и быстрее из них, подскажите **академически правильно написаный фреймвок, у которого есть чему поучиться** учитывая что на дворе заканчивается 2016 год.

Comment: Фреймворк всё же это инструмен реализации(архитектуры, приложения и т.д.)

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это вопрос дискуссионный и дать однозначный ответ без определённых метрик затруднительно? Попробуйте привести в вопросе критерии *академически правильного* фреймворка. Каким свойствам он должен отвечать? Может, вы знаете примеры из других языков?

Comment: Например, из того что мне советовали: Symphony академически очень хорошо написан и его код можно читать как мануал как писать фреймворки. По поводу ZF2 говорят что это чисто коробка с классами, т.е. разработчикам на него ровняться не стоит разрабатывая например свой проек, заимствовать хорошего нечего.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Симфони однозначный лидер.

В ней есть миллион ограничений, которые просто не дают сделать неправильно. Это сильно бесит поначалу, но со временем понимаешь, что уставы пишутся кровью, и каждое ограничение - это не прихоть разработчиков, а забота о тебе же самом.

К примеру, в консольной команде нельзя получить доступ к методу контроллера. И это правильно, потому что если какой-то функционал требуется больше, чем в одном месте - ему не место в контроллере, и он должен быть помещен в библиотеку-хелпер, а контроллер уже должен обращаться к этому хелперу.

Ларавель, в свою очередь, очень хороший фреймворк, но он ориентирован на простоту и скорость разработки, за счет обхода некоторых важных принципов. Чтобы не быть голословным, вот хорошая статья про [недостатки Laravel](http://amdy.su/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-laravel/)

Comment: Позже приведу конкретные примеры, сейчас нет времени

Comment: Плюсанул за Symfony.

Comment: минусанул так как дело вкуса @A1essandro я к примеру больше к  Zend скланяюсь

Answer (score 2):

Symphony или laravel. Оба хороши.
У первого мало инструкций на Русском, у второго их по больше

Comment: И что в них правильного? и что на них нельзя плохую архитектууру постоить?

Comment: Лара как раз научит плохому. А вот Симфони как раз гораздо сложнее в освоении, безо всех этих попсовых фасадов, но зато реально научит пониманию архитектуры

Comment: Чем они лучше yii2?

Comment: @Naumov по крайней мере, правельнее их, многие не напишут. Плохую архитектуру можно построить на любом "инструменте", но это не значит что не надо их использовать

Comment: @5f0f5048ff дело вкуса

Comment: @5f0f5048ff у меня в комментарий-то все не поместится. Yii - бездарный с точки зрения архитектуры фреймворк, держащийся на подпорках, костылях и безумных соглашениях. Это единственный фреймворк, который сначала подключает автозагрузчик, а потом вручную грузит файлы.

Answer (score 0):

А я бы посоветовал не фреймворк а cms с выстроеной архитектурой что бы посмотреть как это работает к примеру `magento` любой версии, время вхождения долгое, cms с ограничениями и сложная но после того как въедишь становиться очень удобной, так как архитектура и структура cms продуманна до мелочей.